# search song using emoji from firebase storage, is it possible?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, emoji

i am trying to make a website where there is a server side which is for admin who will upload songs to firebase storage and a client side who can search the songs using emoji, like for happy songs, smiley emoji will be used, how should i implement this? im stuck. How should i relate the songs im uploading to an emoji, so that when the user searches using emoji the respective songs related to that emoji shows up? That would be a great help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite possible. The server side would not only need to keep the songs but also have some information on moods associated with every song. This way, client app can pass an emoji and server side will respons with all songs that consist of this particular emotion.

For example - song "Happy" can be found by using  or

Comment: yes but i do not understand how to implement this with firebase storage :( all i can do is upload songs there, there is no way to relate the songs with an emoji

Comment: I think you would need to use two different Firebase products for this. You can upload media (songs) to Firebase Cloud Storage. After you upload the song there, you save the id of this song in the Cloud Storage. And then you can create a database in Firestore that simply contains id of the song and all the moods connected to it. So for example song "Happy" could have two rows in Firestore. One for "happy emoji" and one for "dance emoji". This way, when user searches for "dance emoji" you look in Firestore for songs and return to the user songs from Cloud Storage.

Comment: thank you so much! this makes sense! i will try this out right away!